# How to make screen bigger in VirtualBox 7.0

Tags: command-line, server, virtualbox, display-resolution

I try change the resolution in GRUB, doesn't work, I cant find nothing about installing the guest additions from command as is this a server 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: ubuntu 22.04.1 -live-server-amd64.iso downloaded from ubuntu web on 05/02/2023

Comment: Guest additions can usually be installed with a `sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`. The GRUB configuration will not be applied to a VirtualBox VM without the guest additions as that's where the video drivers are located. Until then, you're limited to 1024x768 regardless of what you try to fiddle with 

Comment: sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso, already installed and doesn't change nothing